# Split dataframe column names by special character

Tags: pandas

I am trying to split data frame column name by '\'. My data looks like this.

```
A\B |   X\Y  |  C\D|
____________________
0   |   1    |  1  |
```

How can i achieve below dataframe by splitting column names.

```
A   |B  |X  |Y  |C  |D
___________________________________________
0   |0  |1  |1  |1  |1
```

i'm using pandas library for datapreprocessing

Comment: Will items the columns always appear once only? And will there be differing numbers of the splitting character? e.g. could the column names be `['A\B', 'X\C\E\G', 'J\D', 'Z\A']`?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Split the columns to figure out how many times you need to repeat the values, then construct the `DataFrame`

```
print(df)
   A\B  X\Y  C\D  G\H\J
0    0    1    1      2
1    1   17   19    145

s = df.columns.str.split('\\')
pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().repeat(s.str.len(), axis=1),
             columns = [x for y in s for x in y])
```

#### Output:

```
   A  B   X   Y   C   D    G    H    J
0  0  0   1   1   1   1    2    2    2
1  1  1  17  17  19  19  145  145  145
```